# Owl Carousel - multiple sliders different controls

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm looking at implementing the slider in multiple places and need to control each one individually, some twice on a single page then elsewhere in the site so ideally I'd like them to :

- move 1 slide at a time
- move 3 slides at a time
- auto scroll

I can see how to sort these in the parameters but I am unsure how to separate them so I have control over the individually.

I think I'll need to add different classes into html then use those in the .js to identify.

How can I add classes to the .js?

I'm presuming its here:

```
  f.fn.owlCarousel.options = {
    items: 5,
    itemsCustom: !1,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
    itemsTablet: [768, 2],
    itemsTabletSmall: !1,
```

I've read this on here:

[owl carousel - Set different items number for each of many sliders placed on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329908/owl-carousel-set-different-items-number-for-each-of-many-sliders-placed-on-the)

But I'm not sure how to implement this into the owl.carousel.min.js file as the structure is slightly different or how/where to add the classes.

See: f.fn.owlCarousel.options = {

Thanks in advance

Duncan

Answer (score 3):

You can implement more than one place, but you don't want to add any class. Just add a different ID and you can use it like so:

```
$("#owl-demo1").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop: [1199,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979,3],
    itemsMobile: [479,3],
});
$("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    itemsDesktop: [1199,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979,3],
    itemsMobile: [479,3],
});
$("#owl-demo4").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop: [1199,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979,3],
    itemsMobile: [479,3],
});
$("#owl-demoupload").owlCarousel({
    items: 7,
    itemsDesktop: [1199,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979,3],
    itemsMobile: [479,3],
});
```