# change slider item count (Owl Carousel v2)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to change items count in mobile devices to 2 or 3, right now in mobile devices is something like this
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBsIk.jpg)

but i want to change it to somrthing like this

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuzJx.jpg)

i tried to do this with css but it brokes many things in slider

Comment: There are responsive options with different counts, see this post for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329908/owl-carousel-set-different-items-number-for-each-of-many-sliders-placed-on-the#36761422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes to the javascript file on that page `worldsubtitle.info/wp-content/themes/Worldsubtitle/include/js/my-js.js`

find this code

```
$('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:false,
    items: 6,
    margin:0,
    stagePadding: 0,
    smartSpeed: 450,
    responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
    items:1,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    600:{
    items:3,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    900:{
    items:4,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    1100:{
    items:6,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    1000:{
    items:4,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    }}});
```

and then you change items number (You should write 3 instead of 1)

```
$('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:false,
    items: 6,
    margin:0,
    stagePadding: 0,
    smartSpeed: 450,
    responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
    items:3,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    600:{
    items:3,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    900:{
    items:4,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    1100:{
    items:6,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    },
    1000:{
    items:4,
    nav:true,
    loop:false
    }}});
```